# CGI script error (Python 2.7.5)

Tags: python

```
<p>Credit Card #: <input type="text" name="card_number" maxlength="16"></p>


if (form.has_key("card_number")) < 15:
    print "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-%s" %(card_number)
else:
    print "please enter 16 digits"
```

Whenever the user types in 16 digits to the *card_number*, I want the cgi script to show only the last four digits that the user typed, and other remaining 8 values as x's, as shown above.

However, whenever someone types the number, every single number shows up at the end, and I just have no clue of how to appear only last four digits.

Thank you.

Comment: `dict.has_key` has been deprecated, don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slice to get last four characters.

```
>>> card_number = '1234567887654321'
>>> card_number[-4:]
'4321'
>>> "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-%s" % card_number[-4:]
'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4321'
```

BTW, use [str.format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format) if possible:

```
>>> "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-{}".format(card_number[-4:])
'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4321'
```

Comment: Well I want the user to type their own number, and from those numbers I want to show only the last four digits. Is this the correct way? Sorry, I'm a rookie

Comment: @JasonAhn, Did you put **html** and **python code** in a file?

Comment: so sorry, but which one is html and which one is python?

Comment: @JasonAhn, Sorry, I can't help you if you don't distinguish between html and python.